# Under " dropins folder in websphere there are more than one war files how to generate separate log files for each war"

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-8

- When I run my server which is in websphere,  it generates log file in "**C:\Softwares\wlp\usr\servers\theory\logs\messages.logs**".It has only theory.war in **C:\Softwares\wlp\usr\servers\theory\dropins**
- When I place more than one war files such as theory.war, epic.war, success.war and execute the server it generates single log file in **C:\Softwares\wlp\usr\servers\theory\logs\messages.logs**
- I have to generate separate log files for each war like :

  1. C:\Softwares\wlp\usr\servers\theory\logs\theory.logs
  2. C:\Softwares\wlp\usr\servers\theory\logs\epic.logs
  3. C:\Softwares\wlp\usr\servers\theory\logs\success.logs
- Im using util.logging package.

Comment: Theory is name of your server, it is not related to any wars located in the dropins. In Liberty logs from all apps and server are in single messages.log file.

Comment: yeah i want to create a separate logs for each war..how to perform it @Gas

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have separate logfiles you have to either write your custom FileHandler for JUL, or use 3rd party logging framework as Log4j for example.

You could also use [binary logging](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=logging-configuring-binary-in-liberty) , and then use `binaryLog` tool to filter messages for given app.

However, I'd STRONGLY recommend NOT doing all that, since in new apps that follow 12 factor principles should put all messages to standard out and standard error steams, what JUL by default does. This is used by containers, container orchestrators and logging infrastructure implemented there. Logging infa allows you to filter log messages based on various params without the need for separate log files. And if you have separate log files you will have to manually integrate that.